# How would I spawn a different prefab for a local client and a remote client in Unity with MLAPI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, p2p, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

Sorry if this is a duplicate question.

I found this Reddit post which is exactly my current problem.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/lw96s5/multiplayer_cameras/

However, there's only one comment which isn't that descriptive and doesn't have any links to the 'tutorial'. To rephrase, I have a MLAPI game in Unity with a `LocalPlayer` prefab(has a camera, FPS movement code, and PlayerInput) and a `ServerPlayer`(does not have a camera or PlayerInput component) prefab. They represent different replicated players in my game.

The current problem is the code to decide whether to spawn a local player or a remote player.

Deciding what prefab to spawn:

```cs
        private void ApprovalCheck(byte[] connectionData, ulong clientId, MLAPI.NetworkManager.ConnectionApprovedDelegate callback)
        {
            //Your logic here
            bool approve = connectionData == System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xd");
            bool createPlayerObject = true;

            if (NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClients[clientId].PlayerObject.IsLocalPlayer)
            {
                localPlayerPrefab.GetComponent<NetworkObject>()
                .SpawnAsPlayerObject(clientId);
            }
            else
            {
                serverPlayerPrefab.GetComponent<NetworkObject>()
                .SpawnAsPlayerObject(clientId);
            }


            //If approve is true, the connection gets added. If it's false. The client gets 
            disconnected
            callback(createPlayerObject, null, approve, positionToSpawnAt, Quaternion.identity);
        }
```

Let me know if you need any extra details.

Comment: Use the same prefab and rather let the prefab itself check if it belongs to the local player. If yes keep camera active, otherwise deactivate/destroy it ...

Comment: @derHugo This is not working. `playerCamera.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().IsLocalPlayer`

Comment: Should I use the `NetworkBehaviour`'s `IsLocalPlayer`?

Answer (score 0):

As said I think you should always spawn the same prefab for all players and rather have a component like e.g.

```
public class LocalPlayerControl : NetworkBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (IsLocalPlayer) return;

        var cam = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        
        cam.enabled = false;
        // or a bit more radical
        Destroy(cam);
        // or if your cam is on a sub object with additional components (e.g. usually AudioListener etc)
        Destroy(cam.gameObject);

        // same for all other components that you don't want a remote player to have
    }
```

Comment: When I join the host (on the same computer) it immediately destroys my camera.